# A combinatorial task I just can't solve

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Suppose you have $7$ apples, $3$ banana, $5$ lemons. How many options to form $3$ equal in size baskets ($5$ fruits in each) are exist?

At first I wrote: 
$\displaystyle \frac{15!}{7!3!5!} $
But its definitely not true because I do not care about permutations of apples in one $5$-sized basket. So the real value in divider is smaller than $7!$ (the same logic for other fruits).

Textbook says that the answer is $\displaystyle\frac{15!}{2^93^35^3}$

The method of getting of numerator is clear but divider...

Comment: Are the baskets distinguishable or not ?

Comment: I do not see such refinements in textbook. But according to my understanding if baskets are undistinguishable you should just divide the result to $3!$.

Comment: Nope, if two baskets have the same content, swapping them has no effect.

Comment: Sorry, you are right but still I can't make any refinements.

Comment: It is not a matter of "refinement", it is a matter of knowing what the question is.

Comment: I think what the book is thinking is $\frac{15!}{5!^3}$ because there are 5! ways of arranging the fruits in the basket, but I think the book is wrong because I am assuming all fruits of a given type (e.g. apples) are indistinguishable.

Comment: If there are $15$ different objects and $3$ different boxes the answer is $15 \choose 5$*$10 \choose 5$*$1$ which is exactly the answer of your book. So I think your textbook just considered those apples as distinct objects and the same for bananas and lemons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming baskets are indistinguishable (as well as apples etc), there are surprisingly few arrangements possible. For apples the possible splits between baskets are: (5,2,0), (5,1,1), (4,3,0), (4,2,1), (3,3,1), (3,2,2).

For type (5,2,0) the possible splits of lemons are: (0,3,2), (0,2,3), (0,1,4), (0,0,5) (and in each case the bananas are distributed to make up the total of five fruits per basket).

For type (5,1,1) we have: (0,4,1), (0,3,2) (note that (0,1,4) would be duplicate).

For type (4,3,0) we have: (1,2,2), (1,1,3), (1,0,4), (0,2,3), (0,1,4), (0,0,5).

For type (4,2,1) we have: (1,3,1), (1,2,2), (1,1,3), (1,0,4), (0,3,2), (0,2,3), (0,1,4).

For type (3,3,1) we have: (2,2,1), (2,1,2), (2,0,3), (1,1,3), (1,0,4).

For type (3,2,2) we have: (2,3,0), (2,2,1), (1,3,1), (1,2,2), (0,3,2).

So a grand total of 29.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable interpretation to me, even though apparently the textbook didn't intend this.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to choose 5 fruits for the first basket, you have $15\choose5$ combinations.
When you choose fruits for the second basket, now you have 10 fruits and you need to choose 5 again, so you have $10\choose5$ combinations.
Finally, you are left with 5 fruits and 1 basket, so there is $5\choose5$ which is 1 combination.
Now just multiply the results: $15\choose5$$\times$$10\choose5$$\times$$1$ which equals $756756$ and that's exactly the result from your textbook.

Comment: This is how I would do the problem as well. I don't understand how OP's text arrived at the particular formulation in which their answer is given, though. Any ideas?

Comment: Come off it. Apples are clearly different from lemons. But not from each other (or why mention them).

Comment: @almagest I don't really understand your point.

Comment: @almagest: The answer correctly states how to arrive at the answer given in the textbook. Apples aren't too hard to distinguish from each other. Why they would mention the fruit types if the question is to be interpreted such as to make them irrelevant is a good question, but one for the textbook to answer.

Comment: @Cehrett. A likely interpretation is that the text used that peculiar representation not as a way to illustrate the way the answer was derived but rather as a check, in the same way as if they'd said "As a check, the answer is 756756."

Answer (score 0):

We need to be very careful about what we are assuming is distinguishable and what is not distinguishable. Both @almagest and @windircursed have correct answers with different sets of assumptions:

@almagest assumed that both the baskets and the fruit are indistinguishable while

@windircursed assumed that only the baskets were indistinguishable.

A third option would we to assume that all objects and baskets are distinguishable and then the correct answer would be simply $15!$.

Clearly after inspecting all the possibilities, we can see which interpretation the authors of the problem were assuming when they wrote their answer. Also the form of their answer was simply a way to mask how they came up with the answer: $2^93^35^3$ is simply the prime factorization of $(5!)^3$.

Comment: Isn't windircursed assuming that all objects and baskets are distinguishable?

Comment: No. The fruit being distinguishable allows us to choose from 15 for the first basket, from 10 for the second basket, with the final basket contents automatically determined as what is remaining.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.   I think you are assuming the baskets are distinguishable, though,  when you refer to the first, second, and final baskets.  (I don't believe your answer for the 3rd option is correct, since windircursed's answer is for this option.)

Comment: I'm not confident about my original third answer either now. If the baskets were distinguishable we would have to multiply the second answer by $3!$ to account for basket orderings, which will not get us back to my original answer of $15!$.